# hbase shell command to get all row keys with regex

Tags: hbase

How can I get all the values for keys having regex in hbase shell

for instance, I have something like
Row key               Column
1,2017-05-06          't1:5'
1,2017-05-07          't2:6'

Now I want something like all the column families for Row key '1,*' where * is denoted by all days. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Try this if you want to use regex.

```
scan ‘myTable’, {FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:^1,.*’)”}
```

It is better to use prefix filter given in the previous answer when you know the pattern is at the start of rowkey.

A more complicated regex like following can use the Rowfilter with regexstring in the hbase shell.

```
scan 'myTable', { FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'regexstring:.*-.+[d]{2}1-.*')" }
```

This will match any rowkey with pattern "dd1-" with a dash and one character before it.

You can use some online regex tester like https://regex101.com/ for trying out your regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this :

```
scan ‘myTable’, {FILTER => “(PrefixFilter (‘1,’)”}
```

Source : HBase documentation suggestion https://learnhbase.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/hbase-shell-commands/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in Java:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
RegexStringComparator regexStringComparator = new RegexStringComparator(regexPrefix);
RowFilter rowFilter = new RowFilter(CompareOperator.EQUAL, regexStringComparator);
scan.setFilter(rowFilter);
```